# How archaic is the use of a question mark mid-sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, question-mark

I was wondering how common it is these days to use a question mark mid-sentence to indicate that a sentence contains more than one question, for example:

> How can I get there? and why should I go?

This can be handy from time-to-time, but I'm aware that its use has declined quite a lot.  Is it still widely considered acceptable usage, at least amongst fluent English speakers?

Comment: Gah, this is a dupe that I hadn't seen before I asked it!!!